# graylog-web 1.3 port change

Tags: graylog

I've just setup graylog server on my ubuntu server using the the apt-get feature. Graylog is currently working with no issues, but I would like to change the port from 9000 to port 80/443. I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running applications on ports lower than 1024 in Linux requires root or other types of escalated privileges. Since Java runs in a VM, it will not be able to SUID easily after starting as root.

The recommended way is to leave it run on the current port, on localhost, and put a reverse proxy in front of it (such as nginx or - easier, haproxy).

Answer (score 0):

This is documented [here](http://docs.graylog.org/en/1.3/pages/installation/manual_setup.html#starting-the-web-interface).

```
~$ bin/graylog-web-interface -Dhttp.port=1234
```

Comment: Since I did not manually install it from the tar files, I don't have the bin folder that contains that file.

Comment: This is the web interface startup command. Add the port parameter in your upstart script or wherever you start the web interface.

Answer (score 0):

So you probably don't have the older /bin/graylog-web-interface but instead have:

```
root@ubuntu14:~# grep -R "9000" /etc/*
/etc/default/graylog-web:GRAYLOG_WEB_HTTP_PORT="9000"
/etc/init/graylog-web.conf:  GRAYLOG_WEB_HTTP_PORT="9000"
```

The script to launch the interface is in /etc/init/graylog-web.conf and calls the variable GRAYLOG_WEB_HTTP_PORT. You should be able to change these to 80 or 443 and restart the web-interface with

```
root@ubuntu14:~# service graylog-web restart
```

This should work. Let me know how it goes